# what does "provide for" mean?

Tags: word-usage

> Interviews that asked past behavior questions demonstrated superior validity for predicting performance because they **provide for** an assessment of motivation to apply knowledge/skills more effectively than situational questions.

In above sentence, what does "provide for" mean? I'm confused with the extra(?) "for".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think of it as an extra "for"; "provide for" in this sentence is shorthand for **provide an opportunity for**.  A better replacement would be **allow**.

"Interviews... *allow* an assessment of motivation..."

Comment: But, If I shorten the sentence as this: they provide an opportunity for an assessment more effectively than situational questions.
I still couldn't make the point of this sentence. seems something is missing, but I couldn't tell what is missing.

Which verb does "more effectively" describe? "provide" or "to apply"

Comment: "Interviews that asked questions about how the interviewee had acted in the past were better at predicting future performance, because they allowed the interviewer to assess the candidate's motivation more effectively than questions about hypothetical situations."

Comment: @czh - now that you mention it, the sentence was poorly written to begin with: the author got lost in the middle of that mile-long sentence, and matched "more effectively" with "to apply" instead of with "assessment".   It's not your reading comprehension that's lacking, it's the author's writing skill.

Comment: @czh - Going back to the original sentence (rather than my paraphrase), what the author probably intended was this: "Interviews that asked past behavior questions demonstrated superior validity for predicting performance because they provide for a more effective assessment of motivation to apply knowledge/skills than situational questions."

Answer (score 0):

Provide for in this [case mean:](http://dictionary.die.net/provide%20for)

> permit to be
>            attainable or cause to remain

So, your example is saying that the "interviews that asked past behaviour questions" will "permit" "assessment of motivation to apply knowledge/skills" "to be attainable".

In other words, certain of the interview questions make assessment of motivation possible.